# Codeanywhere DevBox - Laravel giving 500 error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, laravel

I set up my free DevBox (Ubuntu, PHP) that I get from Codenaywhere and followed the installation instructions on the Laravel site.

I set up an `htaccess` in the root directory so it points to /public when I go to the domain.

I am getting a 500 error, but when I put in and `index.html` file in public it worked. Seems like it's not liking the index.php.

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: If you're using apache try check the contents of your `/var/log/apache2/error.log` (or equivalent file) to see if your web server is throwing an error. Also try running `apachectl configtest` on the command line to see if your httpd configuration file is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working, had to set the proper permissions.

`sudo find ./ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
sudo find ./ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data public`

In that order, hope it helps.

Comment: Turns out it was the permissions for the ```storage``` directory for me, just needed to make sure you've enabled write access. I also had to update the ```/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf``` to point to the public folder as the ```DocumentRoot```

Comment: @vonec Yup, I always need to do `chmod -R 777 storage` nowadays.